# Combining EE + CodeIgniter on existing website?

Tags: ee2, codeigniter

It’s been a while since my recent post, but I’ll be very happy, if I can get some help from you guys as well as to share an interesting scenario for other newcomers.

We have a website running on a domain like this:

- domain.tld
- domain.tld/section1
- domain.tld/section2

Our goal is to rebuild certain sections on CodeIgniter, since we need flexibility, which is not available in EE (not because of its limitation, but because of the details we stress on in the new version). Simply said, we try to accomplish:

- EE - domain.tld
- EE - domain.tld/section1
- CI - domain.tld/section2

Is there any reasonable way to do this? I know it’s a matter of “hacking” EE core and / or heavily customizing, but any ideas are more than welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this Dimitar? I'm in the same position and realised that it could be as simple as having the CI index.php file in your section2 folder.

Comment: Hi Jim, not really, since we decided to migrate everything from EE to our own CMS, based on CI.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: ExpressionEngine uses a modified version of CodeIgniter. Ellis Lab maintains their own branch of the main CodeIgniter code base, so expect to run into occasional issues between documentation and actual function.

Second thing: Go to your EE route config file at:

```
/system/expressionengine/config/routes.php
```

and you can go a head and mess about how you want. You should be able to set routes and use CodeIgniter class methods:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

I've never done this in production, just messed with it at some point a few years ago. But give it a go, this could be your solution.